# add rows under <li> with given id

Tags: jquery

I have the next `<li>`:

```
<li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='ids1' href="#">abc</a></li>
<li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='ids2' href="#">hello</a></li>
<li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='ids3' href="#">cde</a></li>
```

I want to append lines under the `<li>` with id of `ids2`:

```
<li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='ids4' href="#">fgh</a>
<li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='ids5' href="#">ijk</a>
```

I think it should be something like:

```
$('ids2').append('<li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='ids4' href="#">fgh</a><li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='ids5' href="#">ijk</a>');
```

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.after` and the ID selector `#`

```
$('#ids2').after('<li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id='ids4' href="#">fgh</a><li class="inner" style="width:100%;"><a style="width:100%;" id="ids5" href="#">ijk</a>');
```

Edit: I just noticed in your appeneded HTML you single quoted your ID attribute, use double quotes since your already wrapping the entire string in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want this, since you don't want to put `<li>`s inside of the `<li>`s without a `<ul>`.

```
$('#ids5').parent().after('<li>HTMLS!</li>');
```

Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lk328/